# Links in header/footer with wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

Is there a way to have working links in header/footer when creating PDF with wkhtmltopdf? I was not able to create links neither with a tag nor with javascript onclick event with function such as

```
function gotolink()
{
    window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is a bug with current 0.12.1.1 version of wkhtmltopdf that misplaces link area in combination with margins 
https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1692